# Why aren't these SHA1 implementations alike?

Tags: php, r, encoding, cryptography, sha1

My question is simple -- with 2 separate SHA1 implementations, am I guaranteed to get the sames output for the same input, or is there space for interpretation in the implementation?

Most specifically My R digest SHA1 implementation and my PHP Sha1 digest don't seem to come together like I would like. Is it that I have a bug or are the SHA1 implementations just giving to different valid hashes of the same message?

In R :

```
digest_token = "Stackoverflow is Cool"
value = digest(digest_token, "sha1", raw=FALSE)
```

output :

```
[1] 4c 70 99 2f 81 b5 32 0d 77 aa 17 b6 da be 69 92 13 a0 44 9f
```

In PHP

```
$digest_token= "Stackoverflow is Cool";
$value = sha1($disgest_token, false);
```

output

```
ef48c200b5d9b844c950f7704e6c03359f8a4e2f
```

I might expect these two to produce the same output but they do not.

Comment: No, some implementations are broken.

Comment: Asuming a working implementation then.

Comment: If you assume a working implementation, then your question doesn't make sense. You've just answered your own question. Are you asking about encoding?

Comment: About your edit: it's probably an encoding issue. It would be really strange if PHP's or R's implementations were broken.

Comment: What is the output, perhaps they are in different formats, hex, Base64, binary. There is also the string encoding you are providing, one may be UTF-8, the other UTF-16 or  another.

Comment: both are output as hex, and input encoding is ASCII... maybe not but im not dealing with any non ascii chars so I shouldnt care if latin-1 or UTF8 etc as they would be equivelent.

Comment: I get `fda997e6a74fb411555490995b262310bab74458` in PHP if run this code after fixing the variable bug. Perhaps you should make sure that you've actually shown the correct string here.

Comment: The SHA-1 for "Stackoverflow is cool" is "fda997e6a74fb411555490995b262310bab74458", and that is what I got  from http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e5ca72d3fee4f3bc0122f344176069ea3f2bf11

Comment: Typo in my code posted, the C should be capital. Now yours an my code will return the same. @Artjom B

Comment: In the php code you need to use `$digest_token` (with the `$`, and spelled correctly). In the R code, try with `serialize=FALSE` so you calculate the hash of the string directly.

Comment: guys its psudocode. I don't need help with syntax errors at the moment ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [R digest package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/digest.pdf) is pretty clear what's going on (emphasis mine):

> The
>   `digest`
>   function applies a cryptographical hash function to arbitrary R objects. **By default, the
>   objects are internally serialized**, and either one of the currently implemented MD5 and SHA-1 hash
>   functions algorithms can be used to compute a compact digest of the **serialized object**.
>
> **In order to compare this implementation with others, serialization of the input argument can also be
>   turned off in which the input argument must be a character string for which its digest is returned.**

The following code produces the same result as the PHP code:

```r
digest_token = "Stackoverflow is Cool"
value = digest(digest_token, "sha1", raw=FALSE, serialize=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly the point of having a hash function. If everyone can implement the same algorithm and have different results, how useful will this hash be?

The algorithm initialize some variables and then does a lot of predefined deterministic 'bit shuffling'. Although theoretically you will still have SHA1 logic by changing this initialized variables, no one does this.

You can see these [variables here](https://github.com/vog/sha1/blob/master/sha1.cpp#L33) (this is only one of implementation of the algorithm, that I was able to find).

```
digest[0] = 0x67452301;
digest[1] = 0xefcdab89;
digest[2] = 0x98badcfe;
digest[3] = 0x10325476;
digest[4] = 0xc3d2e1f0;
```

Comment: Sorry to ninja edits the question, but I guess my real question was WHY aren't these 2 SHA1 hashes dissimilar?

Comment: @gbtimmon then you should be clear from the very beginning. Your original 2 line questions was something like: "are all sha1 implementation produce the same result". And my question answers this perfectly. There is no way that I could have guessed that you had problems with R and php implementations.

Comment: Well my understanding was evolving as I was going.

Comment: @gbtimmon and there is no way I would have guessed which turn your evolution will take and when will it stop :-)

Comment: Alas, neither do I